# How to connect a MySql database to a Microsoft Flow

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am  trying to connect a MySql  database to a microsoft flow, to be able to do it I need to create a connection in Microsoft Flow, How I can do it and how I find the neccesary information within my MySql workbench database.

Answer (score 0):

[use MySQL connector](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_mysql/mysql/)
https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_mysql/mysql/
MySQL
(Preview)
MySQL is an open-source relational database management system. Connect to on-premise MySQL database to read and write data.
See documentation
PREMIUM

Comment: I know I can use connectors but what I mean is to make the connection

Comment: you should have MySQL connection string "Persist Security Info=False;database=myDB;server=myHost;Connect Timeout=30;user id=myUser; pwd=myPass";